# Can camera be placed in hermetic box

Tags: camera

I want to use my Raspberry Zero camera OV5647 (with transistors on a wire) on air so I need to protect it from rain and corrosion. I want to place it in a hermetic waterproof plexiglass box but should it give heat away? Do I need to make a one side of the box by a copper cooler radiator?

Comment: I responded this question yesterday is it a duplicate?

Comment: maybe ... run a test

Comment: @Gil thank you. Could you send a link to the answer, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I remember the question but I do not know where I saw it. You should say which Pi and the size of the box. You should also have a small vent which would be best on the bottom. This will equalize the pressure in the box with atmosphere. Maybe 1/16" would be enough just so it does not plug.  Also put it in the shade, you may have to put a small "roof" over it.

A few years back we used some programs called Ice-Pack, Saber and others like that, they did a great job and created thermal images as well. To do the calculation multiply the voltage 5V times the current, that will tell you how many watts you need to get rid of. Be sure to include the load wattage as well.

Use this search term "calculate temperature rise in a sealed box"
This link may help you: "https://www.heatsinkcalculator.com/blog/how-to-calculate-the-temperature-rise-in-a-sealed-enclosure/"

Comment: Raspberry Zero camera OV5647 with transistors on a wire

Comment: If I make a vent it will be not a hermetic box. Will water in air make corrosion on cam?